Does Modern Fortran (gfortran) has h-adaptive multi-dimensional integration package?
I wonder whether there is an h-adaptive multi-dimensional integration package, containing the algorithm like hcubarture package of Julia language, for modern Fortran?
The algorithm is better if it can calculate multi-dimensional integration directly, instead of calculating it via recursive one-dimensional integration.

Not sure if this helps, given the multi-dimensional nature of your request. But for univariate problems, ParaMonte library has an extended-functionality modernized arbitrary-precision implementation of the venerable quadpack library in its pm_quadPack module. Extension to multi-dimensional could be done by recursive calls to getQuadErr function. If useful and need help, open an issue on GitHub.

Reading the documentation for hcubarture it says "SGJ also wrote an earlier C implementation of a similar algorithm" so I suggest you follow the link and just call the C from Fortran. Note though it also says the rewrite was in part "to eliminate licensing restrictions arising from the use of C code taken from the HIntLib library", so I suggest you checkout was these restrictions may be. Unfortunately the link from the hcubature documentation has rotted.

Further the documentation says "Another free-software multi-dimensional integration library, unrelated to our code here but also implementing the Genz–Malik algorithm among other techniques, is Cuba". The cuba web page explicitly mentions a Fortran interface.
